# Gimp - How to convert shades of one color into shades of white

Tags: colors, gimp

I have this image of colored blocks:
[image: [my image]

They all have different colors, but the constant is that there is a "lightning" effect that makes some sides darker or lighter than others.

How can I make a new block based on one of these, but white (while still keeping darker sides, so different shades of white)?

I have tried playing with the hue-saturation tool, but I never obtain a nice color comparable to the initial ones, I get weird combinations of colors, or it is very bright or with bad contrast. Same with the curves tool.

I'm actually unsure on how to play with the available colors in these tools, to obtain a nice white! (Ideally I'd be interested in being able to do that for any color, but let's go with white for the moment).

Thanks!

Comment: It cannot be white, or your top highlight will not be lighter. Take the yellow one, convert to greyscale, play with simple brightness/contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake might be in thinking about "shades of white". It sounds pedantic, but of course white has no "shade". A darker white is simply grey:

[image]

Here I simply copied the yellow block, desaturated it and adjusted the levels of the new layer until the top face was pure white. The rest just fell into line. Sure some of the faces are actually grey but the button looks like a white button to me :)

Comment: sorry about the 'double juggle' - we edited simultaneously ;-)

Comment: haha no problem, yes it must have been exactly simultaneous!

Answer (score 0):

- `Color>Components>Decompose` and use RGB Model, you get a grayscale image where each layer is one of the RGB channels of the original image
- Set the top two layers to `Lighten only` mode.

Copy/paste the result

[image]